# ASP.net redirect rule

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting

```
<rewrite url="~/forum/viewtopic.php\?t=([0-9]+)" to="~/Handlers/PermRedirect.ashx?ID=$1&amp;action=forumpost" processing="stop"/>
```

This works great, but how to I make it redirect if `t=([0-9]+)` exists anywhere in the querystring?

Example URL's that it should match:

> /forum/viewtopic.php?**t=123**&f=rgrg&rt=224
>
> /forum/viewtopic.php?ty=345345&**t=123**&f=rgrg&rt=224
>
> /forum/viewtopic.php?f=rgrg&rt=224&**t=45**

Can I make one rule to match them all?  One ring, to rule them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do the trick in your case?

```
url="~/forum/viewtopic.php\?.*t=([0-9]+).*
```